# How to intercept Tess4J's output and put it in a logfile?

Tags: java, tesseract, tess4j

I am using Tess4J JNA wrapper and I want its console output to appear in a logfile (any kind of text file).

```
tessInstance.setTessVariable("debug_file", "tesseract.log");
```

also I have a file called "logfile" in `tessdata/configs/` with the following text:

```
debug_file tesseract.log
```

The result was simply Tesseract console outputs disappear, but no tesseract.log file.

I did these according to Tesseract-OCR's [FAQ](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/FAQ).
Tess4J does not have any documentation on how to properly set this in code. I couldn't even find a list of variables, but currently I am only interested in how to put console outputs of Tess4J into a text file through code.

EDIT: The following line of code will make the Tesseract's output disappear  from console but the `.log` file has nothing in it and can't be deleted until the program is shut down.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That statement alone should suffice. Look for the file in your project's root directory. You can specify an absolute path, e.g., `"C:\\Temp\\tesseract.log"`, if desired.

Comment: Well it created the log file now, but its empty and the console does not have tesseract outputs anymore.

Comment: Also if i make a new tessinstance, which also has the tessvariable debug_file but with different name, it does not create the new one, but the first one is still 0 KB.

Comment: I did the same and the log file is empty, too. Although in my case I get a *StackOverflowException*, because Tesseract uses its own logger. I'm using Quarkus, which is based on JBoss.

Comment: I get a file with content, but just after some time.Seems that flush() comes very late.I tested this with 36 page tiff.

Comment: Or the file is written after my little main() finished...?...